# Can jQuery get an attribute from an HTML tag in a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

Inside JavaScript, At runtime I am getting HTML code for `checkbox` inside a `string` as follows:

```
var chk="<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' name='chk1' />";
```

I want to get the `ID` of the `checkbox`.

**My Question is:**

Does jquery support any `api` to to retrive value of `id`?
   **Or**
Do I have to follow the JavaScript `api` to achieve the same?

**Note:**
Currently I am using following JavaScript code:

```
var i=chk.indexOf("id");
var s=chk.substring((i+4));
var j=s.indexOf("'");
s=s.substring(0,j);
```

Finally `s` contains `id` of `checkbox`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pDXv5/1/)**

```
var chk = $("<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' name='chk1' />");

alert(chk.attr('id'));​
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it easily with jquery, as follows:

```
var chk="<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' name='chk1' />";
id = $(chk).attr('id');
alert(id); //alerts 'checkbox1'
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/wp7x4/)

Comment: @kayen Yes, that's another way to do it, thanks for pointing it out :-)