# URL extraction from String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm getting raw HTML data back from a service, and need to extract a URL from the string. Specifically there is a section of the HTML where the URL string exists, and it is a parameter called 'data-url'. Is there a way I can extract just the URL immediately following 'data-url'. Here's an example:

```
let html_str = '<div class="tv-focusable" id="tv_web_answer_source" tabindex="-1" data-url="https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323174/does-the-iphone-8-have-any-sort-of-water-resistance-or-waterproof-manufacturing" onclick="onUrlClick(this)">'
```

I just need to strip out the domain and store it.

Comment: To be clear: I am trying to extract the URL from a String.

Comment: @HereticMonkey -_-, OP means extract url as a string from html text that is in string form rather than html form.

Comment: The structure will not be known so I have no way of knowing where the data-url value will be.

Comment: It was not very clear until the edit that they were getting a string. There are other questions asking similar questions, like [How to get html tag attribute values using JavaScript Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12972446/215552), but unfortunately they are focused on regex, so I won't mark as dupe... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `URL` object from a string using `new URL(text)` and get the `hostname` of that Object. Only thing that remains is choosing how you will extract the url from the html.

Using regex

```js
var html = '<div class="tv-focusable" id="tv_web_answer_source" tabindex="-1" data-url="https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323174/does-the-iphone-8-have-any-sort-of-water-resistance-or-waterproof-manufacturing" onclick="onUrlClick(this)">';

console.log(new URL(html.match(/data-url="([^"]*)"/)[1]).hostname);
```

Using html

```js
var html = '<div class="tv-focusable" id="tv_web_answer_source" tabindex="-1" data-url="https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323174/does-the-iphone-8-have-any-sort-of-water-resistance-or-waterproof-manufacturing" onclick="onUrlClick(this)">';

var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = html;
var elementWithData = element.querySelector("[data-url]");
if (elementWithData) {
  console.log(new URL(elementWithData.getAttribute("data-url")).hostname);
}
```

I would personally go with the html solution, since if (for unknown reasons) the url contains this text `\"`, then the regex will fail (though you could just add that constraint).

Also, if you want ES5 compatibility you should use `getAttribute` over `dataset`. But this will only matter when using older versions of IE (up to 11)

Comment: You don't need to push the html into you document DOM to use it as JS. You can create DOM element out of document

Comment: @Arthur I am creating a `DOMElement` from the `document` object. Then I am setting the `innerHtml`. This way is safer as it will work with `htmlText` containing more than 1 starting elements.

Comment: Okok, I was thinking what document.createElement() was pushing the new element on it. But it don't. So my previous comment are no need to be.

Comment: One issue here is that my code is a Node server so there is no Document object.

Comment: @LeeProbert In that case you can use the regexp solution which will work for every well formed url. Or you can use a node library like [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to convert the text to html

Comment: It might be a good idea to also check for this quote `'`, so change the regex group to this: `([^"']*)`. If you think the request you are doing will never change its response format, then there is no need for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use getAttribute

`document.getElementById('tv_web_answer_source').getAttribute('data-url')`

Even better, use the `dataset` (because the attribute you want start with `data-`)

`document.getElementById('tv_web_answer_source').dataset.url`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: Updated to handle your comment @epascarello

Comment: @Arthur This won't work if the html is of format `<div></div><div data-url="..."></div>`

Comment: Please upvote epascarello's and/or nick zoum's answers, they are good. Mine doesn't take account that it's a string and not a DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing would be to use the DOM to get the information. Set your string of html to a new element, select it, and use dataset to get the value of the attribute.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = `<div class="tv-focusable" id="tv_web_answer_source" tabindex="-1" data-url="https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323174/does-the-iphone-8-have-any-sort-of-water-resistance-or-waterproof-manufacturing" onclick="onUrlClick(this)"></div>`
var str = div.querySelector('[data-url]').dataset.url
var host = new URL(str).hostname
console.log(host, str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

```
url = s.split("data-url=|\" ")[1];
```

Comment: JS have specific function to do this